# How do I toggle the command block output, but only for certain command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a video game in Minecraft, and it has narration. But I also put the command block down to show the narration. How do I silence the "Weather Clear" output, but not the narration?

Answer (score 3):

Non-operators will not see the `/weather clear` output from a command block, but will still see `/say` or `/tellraw` messages.

If you want the weather output to be hidden to OP's as well, you can turn off `commandBlockOutput`:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```